# What are the best authors to read if you want to get better at humor and comedy in writing?

Tags: humor

I’ve read humor like *Three Men in a Boat* and PG Woodhouse, but those comes nowhere close to folks like Dave Barry or Rory Blyth.

What are some sources, blogs, books, articles, authors, etc. that you should be reading if you wanted to add humor in your writing?

Comment: Can you specialize what kind of humor you want to add to your writings? Maybe it is geek humor, or abstract humor, or satire, or sarcasm or anything else from big shrine of humour?

Comment: Would anybody like to clarify the distinction between "authors to read if you wanted to add humor to your writing" and "authors who write funny stuff"? If anybody's familiar with essays and books whose **subject** is how to write humor, those would seem particularly appropriate.

Comment: It's good to see another Dave Barry fan out there. As there are already many answers given below, I would just suggest here that you read all sorts of humor, whatever you can find. Then, stick with the type you think could come from within you naturally. I enjoy a lot of writers' sense of humor, but there are only one or two authors whose type of humor I believe I could do myself.

Answer (score 9):

Off the cuff I would've said Terry Pratchett, Douglas Adams and Dave Barry.

Though to be honest, I have to say I *truly* believe that true humour is more a talent than a skill - it is possible to learn the rudiments, but to excel at it you have to be born with and to it.

And if you listen to the sage advice of those in the industry and succeeding at it, you will hear them say time and time again: "write what you know".  Surely that applies equally to humour?

Comment: +1 for Pratchett.  Though a lot of the funny in Good Omens was from Neil Gaiman.

Comment: @LarrySmithmier, yes, but the funny in Discworld is 100% Pterry's

Answer (score 9):

It really depends on your sense of humor, whether you have one, and who your audience is.

If you're aiming your writing at adults, Terry Pratchet is a great read.
If you're aiming at children (around 8) then Andy Griffiths and Terry Denton might help.

I also recommend you read joke books. But DO NOT use the jokes in your stories, just read them for the laughs. Find out what about the jokes makes you laugh, and what doesn't.

Try Checking out
http://writetodone.com/2008/07/30/how-to-write-funny/

And just remember, absurd characters, settings and plot can be just as funny (if not funnier) then a well said joke.

Answer (score 5):

If I had to name only one source, it would be [M. Helitzer - Comedy Writing Secrets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898795109) - the best book on comedy writing I've ever read. It explains why certain things are funny, describes techniques for brainstorming and writing jokes, and it's also a pretty funny book.

**Books**

My favourite humorists are P.G. Wodehouse (Jeeves or Castle Blandings novels and short stories), David Lodge (The British Museum Is Falling Down, Changing Places) and Woody Allen (short stories). Personally I consider T. Wolfe a very funny author, especially his latest novel I Am Charlotte Simmons.

**Audio**

I'd also recommend listening to some stand-up comedy: George Carlin (he's the best), Eddie Murphy, David Cross, Bill Hicks, Dane Cook...

Comment: +1 for Wodehouse. Some of the funniest prose I've ever read. Hugh Laurie has said in an interview that reading Wodehouse saved his life (Laurie is chronically depressed. And very English. Which might be redundant).

Comment: An old thread, but I agree with you about *Comedy Writing Secrets*. A good book with lots of tips and helpful techniques that are presented in ways that make them easy to apply.

Answer (score 4):

Harry Harrison with the Stainless Steel Rat series and Robert Asprin with Myth Adventures are two others that would be good. It would also probably be worth watching Charlie Chaplin movies, the studied simplicity of his comedy is brilliant.

Comment: +1 for Chaplin. Never mind humor in different media - I think the study of humor in several media trains your brain to do it better in whatever media you need to work in.

Comment: I used to love the Myth books growing up :)

Comment: +1 for ssr (“Liberation by destruction was on the way! We would free them even if we had to kill them all to do it!”), really miss the silliness from harrison. #nostalgia

Answer (score 3):

Scott Adams (creator of Dilbert) published a [blog post](http://dilbertblog.typepad.com/the_dilbert_blog/2007/07/writing-funny.html) on writing humor that could help.

There he covers topics, word-choice, analogies, and more.

Answer (score 1):

Garrison Keillor and his Prarie Home Companion.

Although a radio show, much of the humor could translate to writing.  How information is revealed during a story, small detail by small detail, in what order, is very important for humor, and he's a master at that.  Choice of words.  Some of his show won't translate at all into writing - the excellent sound effects, tone of voice of the actors, though these things too are worthy of study in learning humor techniques.

He has books, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try these classic writers: Jerome K. Jerome, James Thurber, H. H. Munro, Mark Twain, Somerset Maugham and Thackeray. The last few are pretty good at satire.

If you want modern writers, try Terry Pratchett, Simon Rich, Allison Silverman, Woody Allen, Steve Martin and Billy Kimball. The last few have been writing for several media including television.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Listen to old radio clips of the following--

- The Opie & Anthony Show
- The Phil Hendrie Show

Stern was exceptionally funny too...until somewhere around the turn of the millenia he simply stopped trying (or showing up to work that much...*hoo-hoo*)

OnA were especially on fire comedically when they added li'l Jimmy Norton and gave him '3rd chair,' (which was also done by Stern in the form of Jackie Martling and later Artie Fine, who are NOT as funny as li'l jimmy...*hoo-hoo).*

fill-ins on the 3rd chair (and/or guests) on the OnA show is a who's who of guys that can bring the funny. There were absolutely no constraints on the content and Greg Hughes created an environment where funny-guys could snap out of the usual "plug my next show at this radio station" and create priceless moments - almost always improvised. guys like Louis CK, Bill Burr, Anthony Jeselnik, Bob Levy and Patrice O'Neal. (RIP Patrice!)

Hendrie is bit more abstract than all of them -- you have to *REALLY* be thinking to get (and keep track of) how many levels and *in how many ways* his improv is hysterical.  Best if you can get ahold of his KFI/Clear Channel recordings when he was doing syndicated drive-time and took live calls.